# Rails accepts_nested_attributes gives undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a single form that allows for the creation of a Comment and an associated Attachment

Comments Model has:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments    
end
```

Comments Controller has:

```
  # GET /comments/new
  # GET /comments/new.json
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @worequest = params[:worequest_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end
```

In the Comment Form, I'm trying to add this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @comment, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
  (CODE FOR COMMENT)
  <% f.fields_for @attachments do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.input :name, :label => 'Attachment Name' %>
    <%= builder.file_field :attach, :label => 'Attachment File' %>
  <% end %>
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your `@comment` object used in `simple_form_for` is `nil`.  Please post your controller code.

Comment: You aren't defining @attachments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Donovan commented, you're not defining `@attachments`, hence the error.  I had guessed that error was from the `form_for` declaration.

Update your controller `new` action's code to build attachments on `@comment`:

```
  # GET /comments/new
  # GET /comments/new.json
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.attachments.build # Add this line

    @worequest = params[:worequest_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end
```

Then update your form view code to:

```
<%= simple_form_for @comment, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
  (CODE FOR COMMENT)
  <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.input :name, :label => 'Attachment Name' %>
    <%= builder.file_field :attach, :label => 'Attachment File' %>
  <% end %>
```

You could also chose to define `@attachments` in your controller action and use that in your view instead.  By doing `f.fields_for :attachments` the current object's (i.e. `@comment` in this case) attachments association is used, so defining `@attachments` in controller is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added the line to the controller. I don't see any difference in the form.  And I'm still getting `undefined method model_name for NilClass`

Comment: @Reddirt, can you confirm you updated the view as well.  Also could you post the trace to your question.

Comment: My mistake - didn't see the change in the form.

Comment: The form now displays - but the 2 attachment fields don't show up.

Comment: @Reddirt, Oops missed it during copy/paste.  Use `<%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>`.  Note the `<%=` vs `<%`.  I've updated the view in answer as well.

Comment: Sorry, one more question.  I need to be able to submit a Comment without an attachment.  I tried this `    @comment.attachments.build if @comment.attachments != nil`

Comment: @Reddirt, I'd suggest you to ask a separate question for that issue as it's not related to this question.